# Spring Api and Mongo DB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-restcontroller

we currently have a REST Api and it is connecting to Oracle, through Hibernate.

We are contemplating the idea of experimenting using MongoDB as a the database, and I was wondering if people could share their experience.

Obviously it won't be a simple switch. The way we persist and retrieve needs to change. Hibernate might no longer be required.

Is the best practice to design such that the Documents are stored as the Api response should be; it no transformation required?

Thanks for sharing your experience.

Cheers
Kris

Comment: One of the philosophy involved in development of MongoDB, was to dump entire object in the database. In that case, the entire related data, stays together. And anyway, you will have to transform that BSON data stored in database in object form, and then you will have to change it into JSON form.

Comment: thanks. I forgot about the BSON part.